# Laravel - API login authentication check

Tags: php, laravel, api, authentication, laravel-sanctum

As part of learning Laravel API, login and authentification I've created API login route which which works fine, user is loged-in and JSON response returns token that needs to be put into Bearer Token field and API resource `movies` route which allows CRUD operations.

I'm using Postman for testing and when I go directly to `GET /api/movies` route without login or pasting token into Bearer Token I cannot access this route which is desired outcome if user is not authenticated and got this message:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException: Route [login] not defined. in file /home/****/Projects/movie-api/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/UrlGenerator.php on line 444
```

What I'm trying to do, instead of this message to return JSON response that user is not authenticated but don't know how or where to put that code.

I've tried with `Auth:check()` in `api.php` and in my `AuthController`, but could not make it work and could not find anything in Laravel documentation regarding this.

This is my `api.php` and `AuthController.php`:

api.php

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\MovieController;
use App\Http\Controllers\API\AuthController;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| is assigned the "api" middleware group. Enjoy building your API!
|
*/

Route::post('register', [AuthController::class, 'signup']);
Route::post('login', [AuthController::class, 'login']);


Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function() {
    Route::resource('movies', MovieController::class);
});
```

AuthController.php

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);
   
namespace App\Http\Controllers\API;
   
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Validator;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Providers\MovieApiProvider\ApiResponseServiceProvider as ApiResponseService;
   
class AuthController extends Controller
{
    private ApiResponseService $apiResponseService;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->apiResponseService = new ApiResponseService;
    }

    public function signup(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required',
            'confirm_password' => 'required|same:password',
        ]);
   
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return $this->apiResponseService->responseError('Error validation', ['error' => $validator->errors()]);
        }
   
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['password'] = bcrypt($input['password']);
        $user = User::create($input);
        $success['token'] =  $user->createToken('MyAuthApp')->plainTextToken;
        $success['name'] =  $user->name;
   
        return $this->apiResponseService->responseSuccess($success, 'User created successfully.');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        if (Auth::attempt([
                'email' => $request->email, 
                'password' => $request->password
            ])) { 
            $authUser = Auth::user(); 
            $success['token'] =  $authUser->createToken('MyAuthApp')->plainTextToken; 
            $success['name'] =  $authUser->name;
            
            return $this->apiResponseService->responseSuccess($success, 'User signed in');
        } else { 
            return $this->apiResponseService->responseError('Unauthorised.', ['error' => 'Unauthorised'], 401);
        } 
    }
}
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel assumes you are using a browser, so when checking authentication, you are redirected to a login page. All you need is:

```
Accept: application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically set the header to display json even in the browser, you could use middleware. This is how:

1. Create a custom middleware using the Artisan CLI:

```
php artisan make:middleware ReturnJsonResponseMiddleware
```

2. Open the middleware class in App\Http\Middleware and edit the handle method to look like this:

```
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        $request->headers->set('Accept', 'application/json');
        return $next($request);
    }
```

3. Publish the custom middleware
   Open the `kernel.php` file in App\http and add the middleware class we created:

```
protected $middleware = [

       ...

        \App\Http\Middleware\ReturnJsonResponseMiddleware::class, //return graceful unauthenticated message

    ];
```

When you try to access your API route in the browser without being authenticated, you should see a json message:

```
{
message: "Unauthenticated"
}
```